# Tools for searching offline website

Tags: search, indexing, desktop-search

I built a website which runs on localhost and is pretty big by now. What are the tools for indexing and searching my offline website ? For example if my website is placed in the directory c:\mywebsite\ , i just want to submit this directory to the indexing software/tool and then it should work something like Google. I want it to be functional even when I'm not connected to the internet and preferably should be lightweight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not try a desktop indexing software instead?

Comment: Does any of the desktop indexing software allow indexing of specified directories only rather than the whole hard disk .Then i can make a regex search in those indexed directories.

Answer (score 0):

See [SD Source Code Search Engine](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/SearchEngine).  This will index your website, using the language types of the various web files (HTML, PHP, JavaScript, ...) and allow you to search using the langauge structures to your advantage, e.g., "find all identifiers named FOO" (which will only match against identifiers, not strings or comments).